# When is a closure function's state determined?

Tags: javascript, closures

I expected x.gettf() in the following (entered in the javascript console, Chrome) to return true. Please explain what happened. It appears that gettf doesn't access the *current* value of tf, but the value when it was returned from foo?

```
function foo() { 
    var tf=false; 
    function gettf() {return tf;} 
    return {tf:tf, gettf:gettf }
};

x = foo();

{tf: false, gettf: ƒ}

x.tf

false

x.tf = true;

true

x.gettf()

false

x.tf

true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to the attribute `tf` in the returned object `x` rather than modifying the declared variable in function `foo`.

The scope of `gettf` is the function `foo` instead of the returned object.

This snippet illustrates how to get access to the declared variable `tf` within function `foo`.

```js
function foo() {
  var tf = 0;
  function gettf() {
    return tf;
  } 
  function settf(nx) {
    tf = nx;
  }
  return {
    tf: 1,
    settf: settf,
    gettf: gettf
  }
}

var x = foo();
console.log('tf in returned object: ' + x.tf);
console.log('tf in function foo: ' + x.gettf());

x.tf = 2;
x.settf(3);

console.log('new value of tf in returned object: ' + x.tf);
console.log('new value of tf in function foo: ' + x.gettf());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `foo()` returns an object with two properties, "tf" and "gettf".

The statement `x.tf = true;` modifies the "tf" property of the ***object***, but has no effect on the "tf" variable declared inside of foo().  That variable is inaccessible to anything outside of the function.

The following, however, would work:

```
function foo() { 
  var tf=false; 
  function gettf() {return tf;}
  function settf(x) {tf = x;}
  return {settf:settf, gettf:gettf }
};
```